# Get relationship collection groupBy column and not null

Tags: laravel, group-by, relationship

I want to get all the `App\Device` where column `location` is not null or empty AND  distinct.

For example:

```
Device 1->location = "Athens"
Device 2->location = "Athens"
Device 3->location = NULL
Device 4->location = "Berlin"
```

The result i am looking for is an array which will have as `key` the location name and as value the count

```
array(
    "Athens" => 2,
    "Berlin" => 1
);
```

I am trying with the below single line of code but something is not working right:

```
$group->devices->groupBy('location')->filter(function ($value, $key) { return !is_null($key); })->count()
```

**HINT**

The line:

`$group->devices->groupBy('location')`
returns:

```
Collection {#260 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    "Athens" => Collection {#270 ▶}
    "" => Collection {#124 ▶} // Here is a device with "location" column null but i don't want this in my array
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not constrain the condition before your group by:

`$group->devices->where('location', '!=', null)->groupBy('location')`

This should remove all of the null values before it groups them. This will also make the filter not needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
$group->devices()
    ->select('location', 'id')
    ->whereNotNull('location')
    ->groupBy('location')
    ->get()
    ->pluck('id','location');
```